# How can I change some of statements' text style in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, styles, parent-child

I'm trying to show some statements to users from Firebase. There are titles and contents in these statements. Trying to write titles with a boldly styled post. However, I cannot change the code from the android studio because I've assigned the whole description child to a single TextView. instead, I used expressions such as "\ n", which is also used in string expressions. Is it possible to write bold headlines? if so how?

For example ; here is my [image: statement]

Can I write "ilk olarak bulunduğunuz federal devletteki bir..." here by a bold style?

Comment: you want to display the some parts of the description text in bold?

Comment: Yes , can I display?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can display, the approach i use is setting html from firebase

```
<p><b>This text is bold</b></p>
```

and in android side

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    tvDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(strfromfirebase, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else { 
    tvDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(strfromfirebase));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `SpannableString` in this case.

For example if I want to bold the word "Hello" in "Hello World", I would do something like:

```
String word = "Hello World";

SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(word);
spannableString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),0,5,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spannableString);
```

0 is the starting index and 5 is the ending index

Comment: but, You have initiliazed string value in anroid studio. I didnt mean that. I mean that there is a statement which is a child in firebase. I want to display some part of description by bold body. This description really long statement. There are a few titles which I need to display boldly style. You have showed me if I have a string value in android studio, I can change it.

Comment: You can't store the values with styling in the database, instead you can wrap the text you want to style e.g with parentheses `(my word)`, and in retrieving the data, use this to apply the styling

Comment: Well, in the language of Java, we had the possibility to use the \n symbol or \t to skip lines or paragraphs. I was just wondering if it was possible to write boldly styled post. It wouldn't be too bad if it has been actually added it :)

Comment: I was also facing the same challenge, however this is still not possible in Java, hence why I recommended for you to choose another approach to store the items you want bolded, then in retrieving them use the solution I mentioned. E.g you can surround them in brackets or quotes, then as you retrieve them you filter the words with regular expressions and apply your styling :)